# Set Value of Textbox Hidden by ng-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ng-if

Is there a way to set the value of a textbox hidden by ng-if?

I have a textarea that I would like to prepopulate as the page is loading:

```
<textarea id="envConfigJson" rows="5" class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Configuration json" ng-keyup="editConfigEnv()"
                          ng-disabled='!selectedConfigurationEnv'></textarea>
```

At the time of the pre-population the textarea's parent is hidden through an ng-if. Is there a way to set the value of this textarea even though it is hidden from the page? I am able to confirm that the correct value is being assigned to the val property via jquery:

```
$('#envConfigJson').val("correct value here");
```

If this is not possible, I will gladly rethink my population logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to set scope model value and use `ngModel` directive on textarea. So it will be:

```
<textarea id="envConfigJson" rows="5" class="form-control"
          placeholder="Configuration json" 
          ng-model="textModel"
          ng-keyup="editConfigEnv()"
          ng-disabled='!selectedConfigurationEnv'></textarea>
```

Now when parent `ngIf` shows textarea you will see it prepopulated with value provided by `textModel` model.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4D4O6b9BQSDMXEBKFAX3?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This would have definitely been the right move had I not been in an exceptional circumstance (multiple controls on the page dictating the value of the shared textarea).

Answer (score 1):

In my particular situation I needed to substitute `ng-if` for `ng-show`.

This allowed my content to be rendered on the screen but hidden. `ng-if` was preventing the content from being rendered altogether.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference ngIf or ngShow if you use ngModel. Note, that you should avoid using jQuery like I guess you are using to set textarea value.